# If $\gcd (f_1,g_1)=1$ and $\gcd(f_2,g_2)=1$ then $\gcd (f_1g_2+f_2g_1,g_1g_2)=1)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $f_1,g_1,f_2,g_2\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and it is given that $\gcd (f_1,g_1)=1$ and $\gcd(f_2,g_2)=1$. It is also given that $\deg(g_i)\ge \deg(f_i)$ for $i=1,2 $. Is it true that $\gcd(f_1g_2+f_2g_1,g_1g_2)=1?$

Let $h=\gcd (f_1g_2+f_2g_1,g_1g_2)\implies h|f_1g_2+f_2g_1 $ and $h|g_1g_2$, but then I am unable to get any contradiction. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: We can take $g_1 = g_2$ so the answer is negative. The question becomes more interesting if $\gcd(g_1, g_2) = 1$.

Comment: The question that I was solving was to prove $\{ f/g: f,g\in \mathbb{C}[x],g\neq 0\ \text{and } \gcd{f,g}=1 \ \text{and } \deg(g)\ge \deg(f) \} $ is a ring. I just uploaded a part of that

Comment: And what is $f/g$? If it is interpreted as in the usual construction of the field of fractions, then the condition $\gcd(f, g)=1$ is unnecessary, since we can always factor out the greatest common divisor. So your question is also unnecessary. :P

Comment: These are not classes, so this is not the field of fraction.

Comment: So once again: what is $f/g$?

Answer (score 1):

As I indicated in the comments, a trivial counterexample is to take $g_1 = g_2$.

However, if we assume additionaly, that $\gcd(g_1, g_2) = 1$, then the answer becomes positive. Recall that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain). Suppose that $h \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ is a non-unit and $h \mid \gcd( f_1 g_2 + f_2 g_1, g_1 g_2 )$. Without loss of generality $h$ is irreducible, and since $h \mid g_1 g_2$, either $h \mid g_1$ or $h \mid g_2$.

- If $h \mid g_1$, then $h \mid f_2 g_1$, and since $h \mid f_1 g_2 + f_2 g_1$, we also have $h \mid f_1 g_2$. Then $h \mid f_1$ or $h \mid g_2$, the first case contradicts $\gcd(f_1, g_1) = 1$ and the second contradicts $\gcd(g_1, g_2) = 1$.
- The case where $h \mid g_2$ is similar.

So we get a contradiction.